# Change value in dictionary not saving within a looping method

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I am creating 2 strings that are then stored in a dictionary. it appears that the program is not saving the values of the strings.

I am guessing this is happening as I am calling `doRequest` repeatedly and because I am creating the variable that is stored in the dictionary within `doRequest` it is simply recreating them. I have tried declaring the variables outside of `doRequest` however that did not seem to solve the issue I'm having.

Was I on the right track with declaring the variables outside the method and doing it wrong or is there a better way to store the variables?

```
public class Respond
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunServer();
    }

    //public static string user = null;
    //public static string location = null;
    static void RunServer()
    {
        TcpListener listener;
        Socket connection;
        NetworkStream socketStream;
        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 43);
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("server is listening");
            while (true)
        {
            connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
            socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
            Console.WriteLine("connection received");
            DoRequest(socketStream);
            socketStream.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    static void DoRequest(NetworkStream socketStream)
    {
        Hashtable userPlusLocation = new Hashtable();
        Dictionary<string, string> userPlusLocation2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //string user = null;
        //string location = null;
        //userPlusLocation.Add(user, location); //user = key , location = value

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);

        string line = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("respond received: " + line);
        string[] sections = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

        try
        {
            //write if statements for user and location inputs
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = sections[0];
                userPlusLocation2.Add(user, location);
            }

            if (sections.Length == 1)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(userPlusLocation2[user]);
                sw.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine("single arg received");
                Console.WriteLine("location: " + userPlusLocation2[user]);
            }
            else
            {
                location = sections[1];
                userPlusLocation2[user] = location;
                sw.WriteLine("OK");
                sw.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine("location: " + userPlusLocation2[user]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("error stuff: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this `if (user == null)` meant to be `if (user != null)`?

Comment: _was i on the right track with declaring the variables outside the method and doing it wrong?_  Yes, move your dictionary to class level and make it static.  After splitting the input, don't ask if user is null; instead, ask your dictionary if it already has that key or not.

Comment: @mjwills moved `userPlusLocation2.Add(user, location); ` outside of the `if` statement and there was no change

Comment: See [Dictionary.ContainsKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the hastable and dictionary values you will need to also declare those outside of the doRequest method.

```
    Hashtable userPlusLocation = new Hashtable();
    Dictionary<string, string> userPlusLocation2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //string user = null;
    //string location = null;
    //userPlusLocation.Add(user, location); //user = key , location = value
```

The above chunk of code in doRequest creates variables that are local only to the doRequest method so once the method is done, so are the variables. To fix this declare everything you need outside of the method. And be careful to not redeclare it by

```
= new stufff
```

before youre done with it as this will overwrite your values.